# Change text color of default back button in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone

How to change text color of default back button in storyboard.(Both through storyboard and programmatically)? The default color which appears is blue. [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886274/storyboard-uinavigation-controller-back-button-text) question helps in setting text for back button but not the color.

[image: Navigation Bar Image]

Answer (score 9):

The color of the back button will be set from **storyboard global tint color**.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Nitish,

In your storyboard sidebar make sure you select the Navigation Bar tab of your Navigation Controller - not your table view. Then change the background color of your navigation bar to whatever you have set. Some blue color. As far as I know you can't change the color of your back button within storyboard so after you set the Navigation bar controller color in storyboard like the picture:

[image: Storyboard]
Then you can accomplish this by putting the following code in your viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //your color of what you want, I assume you want white based on your background color
```

And the outcome will be like so:

[image: Final Outcome]

Comment: I don't want the color for navigation bar to be changed.

Comment: @Nitish i understand. The answer reflects your end goal. Simply put it in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller that you wish to alter and it will only effect the back button text for that navigation controller, not the navigation bar

Comment: @Nitish please see my edit, i have broken it down further. I know you are not slow and based on your profile well versed with Xcode, however I use this often in my apps.

Comment: In iOS 7+ it is depreciated

Comment: @Nitish Strange. The code is from a iOS 8.0 deployment target with no deprecated warnings. Thanks though I'll alter it to your code

Answer (score 3):

through StoryBoard you can easily set the tint colour.

Select the Navigation Bar tab of your Navigation Controller and then in attributes inspector you can select the tint colour.

Answer (score 1):

Using Storyboards - no code changes - I had somehow reset my BACK button to yellow (and boy has that been irritating!) I clicked on the 'Tab Bar Controller' within the 'Tab Bar Controller Scene' and then changed the 'Global Tint' in the 'File Inspector' Hooray! You can actually read the BACK button now.

[image: Changing BACK button Color]

Comment: My guess is that inspector has changed since Suith's answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is my fix :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

It works for iOS 7+.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the back button for the whole app in Storyboard, select the Navigation Bar in the Navigation Controller. Select the Show the File Inspector in the Utilities Pane. At the bottom of the Interface Builder Document section, set the Global Tint. This will set the color of the back button as well as the Title text of  the Navigation Bar for all the View Controller in your app to the color you select.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 11 you can simply set the tint property for the Navigation Bar object inside the attributes inspector.

See screenshot below:

[image]

It took some time for the changes to take place on the preview for me, but you can see the changes when you run your app.